# How do I correct an active network setting in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I use a wired connection at home and BTFON (unsecured wireless) when out and about. Unfortunately one wireless network has become inextricably linked to my wired network and does not come up as a seperate connection so I cannot change it's location from "Home" to "Public" without also changing the location of my wired connection. Other wireless networks can be treated as separate connections/locations so it is most likely something I've clicked on or changed.

I have tried the following:

- Renaming the connections
- Removing the Wireless network
- Clicking on the icon in active networks and deleting all network locations
- All the above as an administrator
- System Restore
- @Revolter's answer
- Removal/reinstall of drivers
- Route delete 0.0.0.0

---

**How it looks now:**

[image]

**How it should look:**

[image]

---

How can I split these two networks?
Edit1: Don't know if this is relevant but when I connect to BTFON, it renames the wired connection to BTFON.
Edit2: Some more info; As I understand it, Windows stores wireless profiles here:- c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\  but it has not created an entry for the BTFON connection.
**N.B.** The route delete command seemed to work but I had forgotten to reboot, once I rebooted, the networks rejoined under one connection.

**`ipconfig /all` (wired and normal wireless showing as 2 separate connections)**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]   
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.   

C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all   

Windows IP Configuration   

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Dts   
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid   
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No   
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No   
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home   

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 802.11n Wireless LAN Card   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-4F-9A-FF-FE   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d21:d660:9f2b:b507%19(Preferred)   
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.71(Preferred)   
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0   
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 September 2011 16:11:55   
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10 September 2011 16:15:38   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 520095311   
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-AF-2E-6E-00-22-15-63-BB-6F   
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled   

Ethernet adapter Eth0:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-15-63-FF-43   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f878:79e9:1495:b402%11(Preferred)   
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.69(Preferred)   
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0   
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 September 2011 16:11:21   
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10 September 2011 16:11:21   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301998613   
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-AF-2E-6E-00-22-15-63-BB-6F   
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled   

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:   

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:28ef:b2d:a97f:6159(Preferred)   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::28ef:b2d:a97f:6159%12(Preferred)   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

**`ipconfig /all` (wired connection and BTFon showing under one connection)**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]   
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.   

C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all   

Windows IP Configuration   

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Dts   
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :   
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid   
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No   
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No   
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home   

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 802.11n Wireless LAN Card   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-4F-9A-FF-FE   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d21:d660:9f2b:b507%19(Preferred)   
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 11.246.159.104(Preferred)   
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248   
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 September 2011 16:24:03   
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 09 September 2011 16:40:43   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.246.159.113   
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.246.159.113   
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 520095311   
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-AF-2E-6E-00-22-15-63-BB-6F   
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.22.22   
                                    192.168.22.23   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled   

Ethernet adapter Eth0:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-15-63-FF-43   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f878:79e9:1495:b402%11(Preferred)   
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.69(Preferred)   
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0   
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 September 2011 16:11:21   
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10 September 2011 16:11:21   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301998613   
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-12-AF-2E-6E-00-22-15-63-BB-6F   
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled   

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:   

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:   

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :   
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface   
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0   
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes   
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:20d5:99e:a97f:6159(Preferred)   
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20d5:99e:a97f:6159%12(Preferred)   
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::   
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: @Gareth, was that just a layout change? I cannot see a difference in the content.

Comment: Hi @Tog - it was primarily minor formatting changes, such as adding the bullet points for the approaches you had already tried.

Comment: Would be a good idea to also post the result of "ipconfig /all".

Comment: @Tog - I would be happy to give it a try... Would it be possible to come on to chat at some point and @ me - if you want to do remote support, I will be happy to try and directly help you!

Comment: @harrymc here's the ipconfigs The first is wired and wireless working as two separate connections, one location is home the other one is work. The second is for wired and BTFON, which show as one connection so the location has to be manually changed every time I connect.

Comment: I've tried monitoring processes and all I've found out is that it does write to my wired network when the fon connection is made. Registry changes get overwritten or ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The wired and wireless interface shouldn't be on the same gateway. it looks like they do.
what follow should reset everything and you will have to setup your network again.

use **netsh** to reset both Winsocks entries and the TCP/IP stack

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh interface ip reset
```

Then clear the routing table to make sure you don't are having a conflicting one, using:

```
route /f
```

this will let you perform a clean setup assuming the network location are already cleared.

reboot and reconfigure your IP settings and networks locations

---

**Updates:**

You can manage Network Profiles from here

> Control Panel > Classic View > Network and Sharing Center > Customize > Merge or delete network location

Highlight the network then click Delete.

But what I think you clicked on by mistake is this check-box :

[image]

To reset this option goto : 
**HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NetworkLocationWizard** and delete the key **HideWizard**

Comment: This made no difference.

Comment: "But what I think you clicked on by mistake is this check-box :" No, I did the correct one.

Comment: This window should popup when you connect to different networks (assuming you have cleared all the previous configs) it make sense to see all the location set to public when this setting is checked. can you please check if that key is present the registry ?

Comment: The key is not present in the registry.

Comment: @Tog: It's only present afterwards.

Comment: @Tom - Which means I've never checked that box?

Comment: @Tog: The only way to verify that is by successfully connecting to a network that is not listed under "Manage wireless networks", but given that the key not exists I think could safely say "Yes".

Comment: @Tog: Also check `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff`...

Answer (score 0):

What you may need to do is delete the connection that you **don't** want counted as a Public Network.

To do that, click the icon for the public networks (the park bench.)

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

Click *Merge or delete network location*. Select and delete the network that needs to be re-classified.

[image: Merge or delete network location]

The next time you connect to that network you'll be asked to re-classify it.

[image: Re-classify]

*n.b. the network needs to be disconnected (not in use on the merge or delete screen) in order to delete it.*

Comment: Please see the third bullet point in my original post. I have already tried that, when I reconnect to the WAP it rejoins to the wired connection.

Comment: @Tog, try deleting **all** of the listed locations. Should get rid of any possible ties between them.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I did originally, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The safest method would be to do system restore to a date before this happened.

If you cannot restore the system, try first the answer of @Revolter.

If this does not help, you could :

- run a `chkdsk /f /r` to make sure you don’t have any disk errors
- run [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to validate your system files
- install latest network drivers
- Do a [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

Create another system recovery point before starting, and make sure you have backups.

(I hesitate to remark that I have seen cases where Windows required total reinstallation to recover from network errors.)

Comment: I'm not happy about deleting registry keys without more information on what they contain and what they will affect, care to expand? System restore made no difference. Repair Install will lose too many tweaks and settings to be a viable option.

Comment: (1) It is quite incredible that a prior restore point has not restored the network state. You might need to go still more backwards in time. (2) The above registry entries contain all winsock data, and if you want to be sure, you can export them before deleting and compare after the boot the new and old.

Comment: I went back to a Microsoft update prior to the first time I connected to the BTFON WAP.

Comment: I still have a logical problem with this, since Windows keeps all network info in the registry, and system restore rewrites the registry.

Comment: Thank God for reg backup. After deleting the keys, nothing worked at all. Even Revolter's stuff had no effect. Weirdly, I couldn't change the network location or name until after I imported the backup.

Comment: Better always create a system restore point before monkeying with registry. Did you reboot after deleting the keys? I still maintain that if you have an early enough restore point, it should fix your problem. Otherwise you are in for repair install or even worse.

Comment: Rebooted, made no odds, did Revolter's stuff, no different so I imported the backup.

Comment: Did you try an earlier restore point ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I wanted to do a full backup first to save having to reinstall drivers and affected programmes. A restore point from immediately after the install of Win7 sp1 made no difference.

Comment: Well, the only advice I have left now is to do a Repair Install. Sorry.

Comment: Note: I was wrong, and wireless info is well stored in folder Wlansvc. Have you tried repeating Revolter's advice, moving all of them elsewhere, then rebooting? Or maybe moving them, then doing immediately a restore system point.

Comment: @harrymc: You need to actually use `netsh` to restore the default Winsock(2) keys.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: That's why I referred Revolter's answer (so as not to duplicate it).

Comment: netsh didn't restore anything, the network centre showed the connection location as solid black type with no link to change it, also, clicking on the connection icon brought up a read-only pop-up, I couldn't even change it's name.

Comment: @Tog: We are slowly approaching the point of no return, where no one knows what happened to your computer. If you can get help from Microsoft, then do so. If not, there are few solutions remaining besides "zbang" : Repair installation or full-installation. You can and should keep on trying in the hope of doing the right thing by mistake. I would turn off everything possible in the network, for example IPv6 and NetBIOS over Tcpip, disable the wireless adapter, delete(move) the connections in Wlansvc etc., to try to get working the wired connection only, and keep on rebooting.

Comment: I'll carry on prodding and poking until it begs for mercy.

Answer (score 0):

Did some further research, your profiles are listed in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

Set `Category` of your profile to `1` to have Home/Work and to `0` to have Public.

---

In

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures
```

it might be interesting to search your profile and look at the `DnsSuffix` and `FirstNetwork` values.

---

This should be enough to split them; if not, check the other values in these keys.

Or search the XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX or the signature through the registry...

Comment: There are only 2 profiles present, one is the wired connection which doesn't make any mention of the wireless adapter and the other is the good wireless connection. Those other keys don't give any results using ctrl+f find. I deleted the profiles, rebooted and set up the networks from scratch, same old problem.

Comment: OK, the bounty goes here, I'm not happy with any of the answers given to date but this one is, at least, heading me off in a new direction.

Comment: @Tog: You don't need to build them from scratch. You need to make them have a separate home/work/public in the registry. I used [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to localize these keys, filtering by write actions...

Comment: I'll give that a go